# Limit of $(-1/2)^n$ as $n$ approaches infinity

Tags: limits, infinity

I tried plugging bigger and bigger $n$'s into my calculator and the result obviously approaches $0$ (albeit oscillating between positive and negative).

So how do you prove that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n = 0.$$

algebraically?

I tried a few approaches, but nothing that follows the rules I learnt about limits.

Comment: Hint: $-|x|\leq x\leq |x|$ holds for any real number. Use this to compute the limit.

Comment: First note that it suffices to show $(1/2)^x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. Then show that for sufficiently large $x$, $2^x > x$, use squeeze principle to conclude.

Comment: Do you restrict $x$ to be an integer, or do you consider the complex valued function $x \mapsto (-1/2)^x$ defined on, say, $[0,+\infty)$? That makes a difference for the argument to prove the limit is $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer the x can only be an integer, because it's related to a series problem

Comment: If $x$ had not been restricted, we would note that $$(-1/2)^x=\left(\frac12\right)^xe^{i(2n+1)\pi x}$$for all integer $n$.  This goes (spirals) to $0$ as $x\to \infty$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the squeeze theorem:

$$
-|1/2|^{x}\leq (-1/2)^{x}\leq|1/2|^{x}.
$$

And, as you noted, both terms in the left and right of the above inequality go to $0$ as $x\to\infty$.